# When is java main method called?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

1. I have a class(1) having some constructors(arg and no args).
   In another class(2) an object of Class 1 is created using new constructor(). So will main method get called in this case?
2. Ideally when is main method called in any class?

Comment: Note: main is static, and does not require a `new` of the object first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`main` is a static method, the entry point for the program, and is called **once** (unless you explicitly call it), when the program starts, not for each object initialization.

Comment: If every class has a main method, when the main method will be executed? during object creation?

Answer (score 10):

Any class can have a main method.  For example, both your Class(1) and Class(2) classes can have a main method, but only one will be called once when your program is ran.

When you run the program, for example, java class1 - you tell Java that you wish to START the program using the main method of Class(1).  This can be confusing, as you'd think Java would execute each and every main method it finds, but that's not the case. Once Java has found and ran the main method in the class you specified, it will ignore all future main() methods it may find as it's already executed a main method for your program.

You can think of main() as the door that leads into your program, once in, the computer won't try to come in again, it's already in the program! I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Nice. I liked the door concept.

Comment: Thank you - it's the only way that I can understand it - it's funny how one forgets what a struggle some of these concepts were years ago! It's great to see so many people helping each other here.

Answer (score 6):

The `main` method is only called in two situations:

1. By the Java Virtual Machine to start the application
2. By another method (possibly in another class) calling the `main` method, though while this is correct Java it is not best practise

`main` isn't automatically called on the instantiation of a class - as a static method its enclosing class does not even need to be instantiated for it to be callable.

Constructor methods on the other hand *are* called when a class is created.

Answer (score 0):

when you run your class2 (should contain `main` method), `main` method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method will be called by something which does not reside within your program and will be called once to kick off your program. Take a look [here](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html) for more information. As regarding where you should place it, there is no real restriction on its location.